# Apache-Ignite: Kafka-connect data replication hosts issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

Is it compulsory to run kafka sink connector and ignite node on the same host?
If not, what changes I have to make in ignite configuration (XML) file to make it accessible from another node.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connector is a [thin client](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients), it doesn't need to be, however Connect shouldn't run on the brokers either, and if you're in a highly latent environment (consuming from the cloud / remote data center), then it's recommended that you "produce locally"

You'd change the Ignite server bind address (`localAddress` in the communications spi) to make it remotely accessible from any client, including other nodes in a cluster, assuming it isn't already

Comment: Hi completely agree with your answer. What changes I need to do in configuration file which I pass in connector

Comment: Well, `bootstrap.servers` in the Connect worker properties points at Kafka, then there's ought to be another property to point at the Ignite database (I'm not sure, I've not used this connector). Ideally you'd run Connect separately from either system